# Watcom inline assembly docs

Tags: c, inline-assembly, watcom

Searching for manuals and docs about Open Watcom linker, inline assembly and C compiler, as I found official manuals not good enough.
I'm focused especially on C and assembly.
I would appreciate you for links to tutorials, books and etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in time Watcom was a perfect tool for 32-bit C/Asm development. At the same time much information could be found in ftp archives like good old ftp://x2ftp.oulu.fi. It is now defunct, but [mirrors](ftp://ftp.lanet.lv/pub/programming/mirror-x2ftp) exist. Look at the /watcom folder there.

Also try searching older sites like http://www.programmersheaven.com, they are *the* source.

EDIT: as of 2017, most of the information seems to be missing from the link above (Programmer's Heaven), so the only reference seems to be OpenWatcom's documentation and some old open-source software.

Comment: The "this tutorial" link is broken and Programmer's Heaven excluded themselves from the Wayback Machine. Could you either provide an updated link or provide sufficient information for me to search one out?

Comment: I've edited the answer - looks like there is not much on PH right now. Last time I've used Watcom was before 2000, so no further information from my side.

Comment: I've been poking at the x2ftp mirror you linked. Is [this](ftp://ftp.lanet.lv/pub/programming/mirror-x2ftp/watcom/wat_tut1.zip) the inline assembly tutorial you were intending to direct people to?

Comment: x2ftp/watcom/fatmap2.zip contains Gouraud.cpp with some inline assembly. It's not a documentation, just a how-to which can be modified/adapted. I cannot remember the exact reference, most of my knowledge came from reading sources and asking people around.